# Chaos monkey assault on specific instance in multi-instance environemnt

Tags: spring-boot, chaos, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I tried chaos monkey in a single sping boot application instance and I was successfully able to test all the assaults with it. But now I want to try the same experiment in mulitple intances with Load Balancer managing the load. If I will then trigger assault using endpoints that can pass the request to any instance, how can i have a control on the same ??

I tired activating assaults using endpoint but its not allowing to reach the specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you figured this out, given how long it's gone without an answer. That said, I can offer some guiding points:

1. The point of the load balancer is to move the management of load on the distributed system to the balancer itself, so it would require custom logic that would allow for channeling all requests to one and only one instance
2. If you're using a containerization platform like Kubernetes, you could use your kubeconfig to allow access to your Insomnia/Postman/cURL request routine so it's on the same network, which will allow you pod-level internal URLs so you could target a specific instance
3. If you're working with an ingress (nginx, Kong, etc.) you can craft your ingress so that it looks for a specific tag or value in your requests and have it flow to a specific instance

These are simply notional possibilities to help you think outside the box, assuming your use case is following industry standards on a similar tech stack. Google Cloud Platform, Azure, and Amazon Web Services may have further introspection tools that will allow you to do what you're looking to do.